# Panda is printing true and false values

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I have written some code to extract data in pandas, however i am getting true and false values and not the ouput

extract data using groupby pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("All.csv",encoding="ISO-8859-1")
CLO= df.groupby("CLO")

df1=(df['CLO'].str.match("xxxx"))

df1.to_csv("AE.csv")
```

**Input file**

```
CLO Name   Points Fund
AE         100    ABSA
ME          50    FNB
AE          200   SB
MY          300   NED
```

**Output file should look like**

```
CLO Name       Points       Fund 
AE             100          ABSA
AE             200          SB
```

**Output file looks like**

```
1. True
2. False
3. True
```

Goes on like this up to last line of data in input file

Comment: Your expected output is not in csv format so `to_csv` will never be able to output that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("All.csv",encoding="ISO-8859-1")
CLO=df.groupby("CLO")

AE=(CLO.get_group("xxxx"))

AE.to_csv("AE1.csv",index=False)

Answer (score 2):

`df['CLO'].str.match("xxxx")` returns the masking Series.

You are looking for `df[df['CLO'].str.match("xxxx")]` that returns a dataframe:

```
df = df[df['CLO'].str.match("xxxx")]
df.to_csv('filename.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: I get an error messgae when i try to write the file to csv, ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values. the other error i was getting when using a list was that .to_csv is not available for lists.

Comment: @MuhammadAmod Try to pass `index=False` to `to_csv`

Comment: Thanks for the help, i found a solution below

Answer (score 0):

This seems like the default output of the method (pandas.Series.str.match) you are calling, as seen on the [manual](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html).

You could try one of the following options to get the result you want (without a groupby statement):

`df[df['CLO'].str.match("xxxx")]`

or

```
df.loc[:, df['CLO'] == 'xxx']
```